# Copying Image Buffer Output From Video Frame Decompression Callback

Tags: swift, flutter, video-toolbox

I am new to Swift and need to utilize `VideoToolBox` API for H264 decoder. My application is written with Flutter SDK and am utilizing `MethodChannel()` class for invoking Swift functions. To decode frames, function `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame()` is utilized. When the decompression session is done, a callback receives the decoded frame and status. First I need to copy the status to observe if I'm even providing the correct NAL/payload. The problem I'm facing is copying the results given to the callback, then to the function which called `VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame()`. I need to return the status/image to the calling function so that I may create a response for the `MethodChannel()`

My first hacky attempt at this issue was to allocate a class variable that would ultimately contain the data of `imageBuffer` variable that is provided to the callback. But this did not work because of compiler error. I tried allocating memory and copying each element of `imageBuffer` to the class variable.

In Flutter, there is the `ValueChangeNotifier()` class and was thinking could utilize a similar class in Swift, but this doesn't seem like the correct implementation.

The following code is from AppDelegate.swift file. I've provided the minimum code necessary to highlight the issue.

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
      let decodeChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "adhoc.flutter.dev/decode",
                                       binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
      
      decodeChannel.setMethodCallHandler( { [weak self]
          (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
          
          guard call.method == "decodeFrame" else {
              result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
              return
          }
          self?.decodeFrame(call: call, result: result)
      })
      
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    private func decodeFrame(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) {\
        var status: OSStatus = 0
        // Receive encoded frame from MethodChannel
        // convert to UInt8 array
     
        var callback = VTDecompressionOutputCallbackRecord()
        callback.decompressionOutputCallback = { (outputRefCon, frameRefCon, status, infoFlags, imageBuffer, timeStamp, presentationDuration) in
          print("done")
            // How may I copy status/imageBuffer to caller of VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame?
            }
            
       }
        // configure decoder, set sampleBuffer, etc. Note not all steps included, just setting the 
        // callback for the session and the decode. 
        if(status == noErr)
        {
            status = VTDecompressionSessionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, formatDescription: formatDesc!, decoderSpecification: nil, imageBufferAttributes: nil, outputCallback: &callback, decompressionSessionOut: &session);
        } else{
            rtn = ["image": [], "status": status];
            return result(rtn)
        }

        if(status == noErr) {
            status = VTDecompressSessionDecodeFrame(session!, sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer!, flags:               
                [._EnableTemporalProcessing], frameRefCon: frameRef, infoFlagsOut: nil)
        }

        // Return [UInt8] image and status code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the following override for the function:

```
func VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame(
    _ session: VTDecompressionSession,
    sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
    flags decodeFlags: VTDecodeFrameFlags,
    infoFlagsOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<VTDecodeInfoFlags>?,
    outputHandler: @escaping VTDecompressionOutputHandler
) -> OSStatus
```

There's also a way to pass self to the callback but haven't really looked into that.